# Why can I access C++ map elements with a for loop but not individually?

Tags: c++, dictionary, debugging, data-structures

I'm having a bit of a problem with the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, int> m; //Dictionary map

int main() {

    std::ifstream dictionaryFile("dictionary.txt");

    std::string str;
    int probability = -1;

    //Read dictionary.txt and assign to map
    while(std::getline(dictionaryFile, str)) {

        if(str.find("#!comment:") == std::string::npos) {   //Not a comment
            m.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(str, probability));
        }
        else {
            probability++;
        }

    }

    dictionaryFile.close();


    //Iterate and print through map -- THIS WORKS
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = m.begin(); pos != m.end(); ++pos) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << pos->first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value: " << pos->second << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    //Is "very" in the map? -- THIS DOES NOT WORK
    std::cout << m.find("very")->second << std::endl;

    if(m.find("very") != m.end()) {
        std::cout << "found it" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "did not find it" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I read in the "dictionary.txt" file, and insert each word into a map. Either 1 or 2 is the value associated with that key, depending on the probability of the word.

I'm able to iterate through the map and print it's elements from within a for-loop, as shown. But I'm unable to access each element individually with m.find(), m.count(), or the [] operator. Each of those show as if the map is empty.

Do I have a piece of syntax wrong? Have I discovered a bug in std::map? Any help would be appreciated!

Here is [dictionary.txt](https://textuploader.com/d3nfm) if you would like it.

Comment: The link to the file is invalid. Another reason why you should include all the relevant content in the post.

Comment: I fixed the link, hopefully it should work for you now. Thanks.

Comment: That's totally missing the point. You should create a [mcve] with a small input file and add the contents of the input file to your post.

Comment: which c++ are you using?

Comment: `m.find("very")->second` is only going to work if `"very"` is in the map.  You're not allowed to dereference `map::end()`.

Comment: Re: _"Have I discovered a bug in std::map?"_ -- NO

Comment: @RSahu I'm uploading dictionary.txt as a separate file because it is quite long and would take up many lines if posted normally.

Comment: @EvilTeach c++98 I believe.

Comment: @SidS I chose to test "very" because thats one of the words being inputted via dictionary.txt. It shows as being in the map when I print all elements out via the for loop.

Comment: @paddy I know, that was mostly a joke :)

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this file contains windows CRLF line-endings, and you're running this program on a non-windows system.  Try outputting the _length_ of each line when you read it in.  I would not be surprised if you find that "very" is 5 characters long.

Comment: @JohnBettencourt, So maybe you have `"very "` with a space in it or something.  It's rather difficult to help you when you selectively hand out information.  Modify your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Paddy You are absolutely right. I'm running this program on a linux virtual machine. Each word is showing as one longer than it actually is.

Comment: @paddy I tried m.find("very ") but that still gives me nothing. What else could I try searching for?

Comment: Are you sure `m.insert(...)` is correct, that shows as a C++17 member function. [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) Why not `m[str] = probability`?

Comment: @paddy I ran the code with a new input file I created in Linux and it worked. Thank you! That being said, is there any way to easily convert a text file from this current format I have it in to one that Linux will read properly?

Comment: I was able to save it with Linux line endings via a text editor I had. Now the original problem is solved.

Comment: @JohnBettencourt Realize that this code `std::ifstream dictionaryFile("dictionary.txt");` lied to the Linux runtime -- the file was not a text file, but a file that contained strange characters, and possibly the EOF marker was also off-kilter.

Comment: @JohnBettencourt Your code actually works as you expect, see https://glot.io/snippets/f730c9nnd8
Check out your file format, or if it's not somehow interpreting a CR for a space in a CRLF-ended line, or something like that. You could also try running `std::locale::global(std::locale(""))` first thing in your program (especially on Windows), to guarantee it can read files saved by system-localized editors, e.g. Notepad. EDIT: nevermind, did not read your previous comments before doing it myself.

Comment: `dictionary.txt` only needs to needs a few lines long for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains Windows CRLF line endings `\r\n`.  These are automatically translated into `\n` with the default `istream` processing on Windows.  However, you are on a Linux system that will be treating your `\r` character as nothing particularly special.

There are various ways around this.  The simplest would be to not use such files as inputs on Linux.  You can find answers elsewhere on this site for how to convert line-endings in the shell.

If you absolutely want your program to handle them, then you need to introduce some extra code.  It can be as simple as checking the last character:

```
if (!str.empty() && str.back() == '\r')
    str.pop_back();
```

For pre-C++11 standard library that doesn't have `std::string::pop_back`, you can just call `str.erase(str.size()-1)` instead.